# Sorting nested array of objects with dynamic key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to create a sorting function that sorts a nested array of objects while giving a key dynamically (with different depths).

```
sortByKey(array, key){
    var splitKey = key.split(".");
    if(splitKey.length = 2){
      return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[splitKey[0]][splitKey[1]]; var y = b[splitKey[0]][splitKey[1]];
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
      });
    } else {
      return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
      });
    }
  }
```

I want to get rid of the `if - else` and use a `for` loop instead. The goal is that the function works with 'name', 'name.first' and 'name.first.another' (as an example). Is there a way to do this dynamically?

In other words, I want to use the same function with different arrays. So with one array I want to sort it calling sortByKey(array1, 'name') and with another sortByKey(array2, 'location.address') and maybe with a third sortByKey(array3, 'location.address.postalcode') or something like that.

Comment: `if(splitKey.length = 2)` is unlikely to do what you think.

Comment: can you provide an example of what ur trying to accomplish ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract property extracting function

```
function prop(key) {
  var keys = key.split('.');

  return keys.reduce.bind(keys, function(obj, name) {
    return obj[name]
  })
}
```

and use it to well extract values :)

```
sortByKey(array, key){
    var getKey = prop(key);

    return array.sort(function(a, b){
      var x = getKey(a); var y = getKey(b);
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    })
  }
```

Comment: This solution is so simple and elegant that deserves more up votes :)

Comment: `.reduce.bind()` (and subsequently `getKey()`) — Thank you for showing a good example of [**currying**](https://www.google.com/search?q=JS+currying+with+bind++site%3Astackoverflow.com)!

Comment: bind is not necessary here. it is superfluous and irritating. what is the actual purpose of this?

Comment: @NinaScholz "it is superfluous and irritating" well, it is your opinion. Bind wasn't that irritating back in 2016 when arrow functions required transpilation.

Comment: `bind` was neither back in time not neccessary nor today. ther is no use of `this`.

Comment: @NinaScholz Once again, this sounds very opinionated. There is a lot of use cases for using `this` in javascript. But the main reason for using `bind` in the code above is not to capture this but for partially apply the `reduce` function.

Comment: no. it simply works without binding. just try this.

Comment: What "no"? It works with bind as well. just try it.

Comment: if it works with and without, it is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this:

```
function sortByKey(array, key){
    var splitKey = key.split(".");

    return array.sort(function(a, b) {
        var ta = a;
        var tb = b;
        for (var i=0; i<splitKey.length; i++) {
            ta = ta[splitKey[i]];
        };
        /// return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0)); // Too complex ;-)
        return a - b;

    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a misused assignment, where it should be a comparison.

```
if (splitKey.length === 2) {
//                  ^^^
```

A shorter approach could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
function sortByKey(array, key) {
    var getValue = function (o, k) { return o[k]; },
        keys = key.split(".");

    return array.sort(function (a, b) {
        return keys.reduce(getValue, a) - keys.reduce(getValue, b);
    });
}

var array = [{ a: 5, b: { c: 2 } }, { a: 7, b: { c: 1 } }, { a: 1, b: { c: 3 } }];



sortByKey(array, 'a');
console.log(array);
sortByKey(array, 'b.c');
console.log(array);
```

ES6

```js
function sortByKey(array, key) {
    const getValue =
        (keys => object => keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k], object))
        (key.split('.'));

    return array.sort((a, b) => getValue(a) - getValue(b));
}

var array = [{ a: 5, b: { c: 2 } }, { a: 7, b: { c: 1 } }, { a: 1, b: { c: 3 } }];

sortByKey(array, 'a');
console.log(array);
sortByKey(array, 'b.c');
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```